# How to show a popup menu above the clicked button?

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to show a popup menu, using the provided `showMenu(...)` API, above the clicked button?

Basically the opposite of the following image (here the menu is below and not above the red button):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try `PopupMenuButton` which has an optional `offset` parameter that sets the relative position of the displayed menu from the button. By default Flutter engine decides whether the menu should be displayed above or below. You can override this behaviour with `offset` but you need to figure out the offset value. There are ways to do it dynamically but depending on your widgets it might be a constant value in your case.

Check out the following example, see how the top and bottom menus are displayed. At the centered version I added an offset so that the menu will be displayed right above.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Stack(children: const [
                  MyMenu(title: 'Menu at top', alignment: Alignment.topCenter),
                  MyMenu(
                    title: 'Menu at center with offset',
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    offset: Offset(0, -170),
                  ),
                  MyMenu(
                      title: 'Menu at bottom', alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter)
                ]))));
  }
}

class MyMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final Alignment alignment;
  final Offset offset;
  const MyMenu(
      {required this.title,
      required this.alignment,
      this.offset = const Offset(0,0),
      Key? key})
      : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      alignment: alignment,
      child: PopupMenuButton<int>(
        offset: offset,
        itemBuilder: (context) => const [
          PopupMenuItem<int>(
              value: 0,
              child: Text(
                'Item 0',
              )),
          PopupMenuItem<int>(
              value: 1,
              child: Text(
                'Item 1',
              )),
          PopupMenuItem<int>(
              value: 2,
              child: Text(
                'Item 2',
              )),
        ],
        child: Text(title),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```